# Enity Framework Core: Handling large number of enum-like fields

Tags: mysql, sql, entity-framework-core

I am currently facing the following problem:
I have a model class `LargeDataClass` with many fields (200+).
Many of these fields (~50-80) are enum-like (i.e. they can be filled out with certain sets of options in the UI).
Now my approach was to model these as enum classes, like

```
[Table("tbl_enum_one")]
class EnumOne {
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}

[Table("tbl_large_dataclass")]
class LargeDataClass {
   public EnumOne EnumOne { get; set; }
   public int EnumOneId { get; set; }
   //...
}
```

This has the major advantage of being easily extendable (to add a dropdown option in the UI, just add a row to the table).
Now I am facing some concerns/problems:

1. When I fetch my model class `LargeDataClass` from the DB with all its enum fields included, there will be a lot of joins (as I stated above, there are like 50 to 80 of these fields). I am worried that will have a big impact on query performance. Plus create/update/delete might be quite slow due to the large number of indexes to be updated.
2. MySQL won't even let me create a table `tbl_large_dataclass` with that many FKs (too many indexes on a single table).

So now I am considering two (in my view really unfortunate) options:

1. Using regular enums, so no enum classes with their own tables, storing them as simple int/string fields in the DB. This would cause no performance concerns at all, but unfortunately, the 'live' extendability is quite important, so this option would only be the last resort.
2. Using the Enum classes, but having just the ID of the enum in the `LargeDataClass`, so kind of keeping the fact that this is a foreign key secret from the DB. If I wanted to display a `LargeDataClass` object somewhere, I would have to separately fetch the enum classes. Plus I would have to make extra sure everywhere that I only use Ids that are really present in the enum table.

I am really unsure what would be the best approach here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Database is not an object store and you have to design it accordingly. I have changed you schema and only two tables are needed for storing dropdown values.

```
[Table("tbl_enum_type")]
public class EnumType {
  public int ID { get; set; } // PK
  public string Name { get; set; }
}

// PK (EnumTypeId, Id) - reusing the same index for dropdown generation
[Table("tbl_enum_value")]
public class EnumValue {
  public int ID { get; set; } 
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public int Order { get; set; } // for dropdown ordering
  public int EnumTypeId { get; set; } 
  public EnumType EnumType { get; set; }
}

// store only ID's, no FK
[Table("tbl_large_dataclass")]
public class LargeDataClass {
   public int EnumOneId { get; set; }    // EnumTypeId 1
   public int EnumSecondId { get; set; } // EnumTypeId 2
   //...
}
```

For generating dropdowns, you have to cache EnumType and EnumValue tables in memory in useful structure.

Override method `SaveChanges/SaveChangesAsync` and check saved Id's according to cached data.

It will not help if your database is changed via SQL, but here we have trade-off between performance and consistency. Probably good trigger may help here.

**UPDATE:**

Consider to restructure LargeDataClass to two tables

```
[Table("tbl_option_bag")]
public class OptionBag {
   public int Id { get; set; }    
   public ICollection<Option> Options { get; set; } 
}

[Table("tbl_options")]
public class Option {
   public int Id { get; set; } 
   public int OptionBagId {get; set; }
   public int EnumTypeId { get; set; } 
   public int EnumId { get; set; } 
   //...
}
```

Here you can use FK and DTO can be generated on selecting Options navigation property.

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful. So to make entirely sure, the EnumOneId field points to the ID column in EnumValue, right?

Comment: Yes, but, there is composite key (EnumTypeId, Id)

Comment: LargeDataClass also should be restructured. I don't believe that you need 200 fields.

Comment: Okay, thanks, I think I got it now. The dataclass just happens to be a domain object, whose fields all logically belong to it. I am not sure if I should split up the model class just for the sake of reducing its size, when I will be joining these fields together again anyway when I fetch the model from the db (because they will be displayed and edited together).

Comment: Performance is not a EF design goal ;) Updated answer with restructured LargeDataClass table.